# Handle assert statements across FFI boundary?

Tags: rust, ffi

I have the following function which is a tauri command. The purpose of this function is to detect whether the file in a path is a valid video file

This code panics when given a path to a file which is not a valid video. (Specifically i'm giving it a .rs file)

```rs
use std::{panic, thread};

use libvmaf_rs::video::Video;

#[tauri::command]
pub async fn validate_video(path: String) -> Result<(), String> {
    let did_panic = thread::spawn(|| match Video::new(path, 640, 480) {
        Ok(_) => Ok(()),
        Err(e) => Err(e.frames().into_iter().map(|f| format!("{f:?}")).fold(
            String::new(),
            |mut prev, next| {
                prev.push_str(&next);
                prev.push_str("\n");
                prev
            },
        )),
    });

    match did_panic.join() {
        Ok(e) => e,
        Err(e) => Err("Panicked while trying to load video".to_string()),
    }
}
```

As you can see, I attempted to handle this by wrapping the entire handler in a thread and checking if the thread panicked, but unfortunately this still crashes my entire program when this function panics. I have no control of the underlying library. I've also tried `panic::catch_unwind` with the same results

Here's the console output. This is coming from libswscale which is linked to the ffmpeg-next crate

```
[sunrast @ 0x7f1e44003040] this is not sunras encoded data
[image2 @ 0x7f1e44000900] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: sunrast, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Assertion desc failed at libswscale/swscale_internal.h:725
```

It seems that there's some sort of assertation happening in libswscale which is panic-ing before it gets to rust. There's no way to recover from this!

Comment: That unfortunately does not appear to be a panic, but rather a process abort from the C library. You won't be able to catch this with a thread or with `catch_unwind`. You may have to spin up a separate process instead.

Comment: I see, so would that be an OS thread? What's the mechanism to do this in rust?

Comment: Not an OS thread (which you already have), an OS process. Although I'm not sure this is a good idea, I also don't know if this library promises to always crash on invalid files.

Comment: libswscale seems to. I fixed this by adding a guard before trying to instantiate a scaler. If any dimension of the source resolution is 0, early return from my constructor. Do the same for unknown pixel formats. Essentially instead of trying to recover from this, I'm trying to prevent it from happening in the first place